# Determine angle between camera position and world point in 3D engine

Tags: c++, opengl, linear-algebra, quaternions, glm-math

I want to determine the horizontal and vertical angle, from a camera's position to a world point, in respect to the camera's forward axis.

My linear algebra is a bit rusty, but given the camera's forward, up, and right vector, for example:

```
camForward = [0 0 1];
camUp = [0 1 0];
camRight = [1 0 0];
```

And the camera position and world point, for example:

```
camPosition = [1 2 3];
worldPoint = [5 6 4];
```

The sought-after angles should be determinable by first taking the difference of the positions:

```
delta = worldPoint-camPosition;
```

Then projecting it on the camera axes using the dot products:

```
deltaHorizontal = dot(delta,camRight);
deltaVertical = dot(delta,camUp);
deltaDepth = dot(delta,camForward);
```

And finally computing angles as:

```
angleHorizontal = atan(deltaHorizontal/deltaDepth);
angleVertical = atan(deltaVertical/deltaDepth);
```

In the example case, this yields that both angles become ~76°, which seems reasonable; varying the positions and axes also seem to give reasonable results.

Thus, if I am not getting the angles I expect, it should be due to that I am using either incorrect position and/or camera axes. It is worth noting that the 3D engine is using OpenGL and GLM.

I am fairly certain that the positions are correct, as moving around in the scene and inspecting the positions in relation to known reference points give consistent and correct results. Leading me to believe that I am using the wrong camera axes. To get the angles I am using (the equivalent of):

```
glm::vec3 worldPoint = glm::unProject( glm::vec3(windowX, windowY, windowZ), viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, glm::vec4(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight));

glm::vec3 delta = glm::vec3(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y, worldPoint.z);

float horizontalDistance = glm::dot(delta, cameraData->right);
float verticalDistance = glm::dot(delta, cameraData->up);
float depthDistance = glm::dot(delta, cameraData->forward);

float horizontalAngle = glm::atan(horizontalDistance/depthDistance)
float verticalAngle = glm::atan(verticalDistance/depthDistance)
```

Each frame, `forward`, `up`, and `right` are read from a view matrix, `viewMatrix` which in turn is produced by a converting a quaternion, `Q`, which holds the camera rotation which is controlled by mouse:

```
void updateView(CameraData * cameraData, MouseData * mouseData, MouseParameters * mouseParameters){
    
    float deltaX = mouseData->currentX - mouseData->lastX;
    float deltaY = mouseData->currentY - mouseData->lastY;

    mouseData->lastX = mouseData->currentX;
    mouseData->lastY = mouseData->currentY;
    
    float pitch = mouseParameters->sensitivityY * deltaY;
    float yaw   = mouseParameters->sensitivityX * deltaX;

    glm::quat pitch_Q = glm::quat(glm::vec3(pitch, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::quat yaw_Q = glm::quat(glm::vec3(0.0f, yaw, 0.0f)); 

    cameraData->Q = pitch_Q * cameraData->Q * yaw_Q;
    cameraData->Q = glm::normalize(cameraData->Q);

    glm::mat4 rotation = glm::toMat4(cameraData->Q); 

    glm::mat4 translation = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    translation = glm::translate(translation, -(cameraData->position));

    cameraData->viewMatrix = rotation * translation;

    cameraData->forward = (cameraData->viewMatrix)[2];
    cameraData->up = (cameraData->viewMatrix)[1];
    cameraData->right = (cameraData->viewMatrix)[0];
 }
```

However, something goes wrong, and the correct angles are seemingly only produced while looking along, or perpendicular to, the world z-axis ([0 0 1]). Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Your `deltaHorizontal/Vertical/Depth` is simply `viewMatrix*delta`.

Comment: Extending on what @ybungalobill said: Since your input is actually window space, it is not neccesarily to unproject it into world space (conceptually inverting projection **and** view), and then to forward-transform it into view space again, you simply can unproject to view space to begin with. This of course implies that for getting the angles from a window space point, you don't need the view matrix / camera position and orientation at all, since the projection matrix alone will define which angle relative to the camera will end up on which window space locations.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! @derhass , my aim with this exercise is actually to illustrate (in a roundabout way) the horizontal and vertical angles the projection matrix impose on the camera's pixels – since they aren't linearly going from the minimum and maximum field-of-view angles.